# Pyinstaller .app bundle won't open on Mac

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller

I've created a wxPython GUI application and I want to distribute it to be run on macOS.

First of all, here's my folder structure:

```
root/
├── MyApp.py
|
├── scripts/
|   ├── script.py
|
├── resources/
|   ├── file1.json
|   ├── file2.txt
```

The `MyApp.py` file runs `script.py` and `script.py` references the files in the `resources` folder.

To create the `.app` bundle, I've used `Pyinstaller` like so:

```
cd /path/to/root/folder
pyinstaller MyApp.py --windowed
```

This creates an `.app` file but this immediately closes when I try to open it.

To investigate the issue, I went here:

```
MyApp.app > Contents > MacOS > MyApp (A Unix executable)
```

This runs the app from the Terminal, but I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/MyAccount/resources'

In `script.py`, I get a reference to the `root` directory using `os.getcwd()`, but running the app seems not to use this relative path when trying to access the `resources` folder. I'm very new to this so I'm not sure where I might be going wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [runtime information](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information) to get the path to the folder where your code is located:

```
import sys
import os

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # this is a Pyinstaller bundle
    root_path = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    # normal python process
    root_path = os.getcwd()
```

Then, for example, your `file1.json` cold be accessed using:

```
path_to_file1 = os.path.join(root_path, 'resources', 'file1.json')
```

However, the two files in your `resources` folder will probably not get included in your app folder without specifying them in your `Pyinstaller` command line (or in a `.spec` file):

```
pyinstaller --windowed --add-data "resources/file1.json:resources" --add-data "resources/file2.txt:resources" MyApp.py
```

You might be able to just specify the folder in the `--add-data` option, like this:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --add-data "resources:resources" MyApp.py
```

But I have never tried exactly that.